# Is there a way to convert a string to a double or int in one statement inside of a JOptionPane?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I'm new to Java and the site. First off, thanks for any input, I appreciate it.

So, for a homework assignment, I am asked to use dialog input and convert it to a double in one statement. I have been searching my text and the web for hours to no avail. Would someone so kindly direct me, PLEASE? I don't want the answer, just a direction, thanks!

Comment: `Double.parseDouble()` & `Integer.parseInt()`.

Comment: *"for a homework assignment, I am asked to use dialog input and convert it to a double in one statement."*  Your teacher deserves a good smack upside the head..

Comment: First week assignment. I thought he should have gone through this with us. There is no explanation during the lecture or text that would lead you believe that this is possible. In everything he has done, it is implied that JOptionPane is leading the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double inputNum = Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number"));
```

or for int:

```
int inputNum = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter number"));
```

Often consulting the API can answer many questions.

Comment: You can drop the `null`.

Comment: I was not aware that the JoptionPane could be inserted that way.

Comment: @AndrewThompson See [`JOptionPane#showInputDialog(Object message)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  Of course!  How remiss of me (not to check the JavaDocs first)!

Comment: @AndrewThompson It's OK ;)